# Vert.x address already in use: bind - Not kill processes (Windows)

Tags: windows, rest, intellij-idea, runtime-error, vert.x

I'm creating a simple ***REST Server*** using ***Vert.x*** on ***intelliJ IDEA***. When I run to test it, **processes never are stopped** after clicking the stop button from intelliJ. I undestand this because if I try to run, stop and rerun will appear the error "*Address already in use: bind*" so each time I must search java processes and kill them by Task Manager. **Someone know a better solution?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved changing in my *build.gradle.kts* this line of code:

```
tasks.withType<JavaExec> { args = listOf("run", mainVerticleName, "--redeploy=$watchForChange", "--launcher-class=$launcherClassName", "--on-redeploy=$doOnChange")}
```

With this:

```
tasks.withType<JavaExec> { args = listOf("run", mainVerticleName, "--launcher-class=$launcherClassName", "--on-redeploy=$doOnChange")}
```

So I removed the ***"--redeploy=$watchForChange"*** and it works fine.